# preg_match_all starting from specific html tag and ending with it

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-match

I have a source page with a table which consists of 15 rows with this content:

```
<tr class="hlRow" onclick="window.location=link11.href" onmouseover="rowOver(11)" onmouseout="rowOut(11,'#cad9ea')">
  <td class="row3">Latest news</td>
  <td class="row3" id="row_6_11"><a onclick="servOC(11,'/link-to-page.html','',ihTri11)"><img class="tog" id="ihTri11" src="up.png" title="Toggle" height="19" width="19" /></a>14.7w</td>
  <td class="row3" id="name11"><a href="/link-to-page.html" style="float: right; color: green; font-weight: bold;" title="+2 rating, 2 comments">+2<img src="star.png" alt="rating" style="margin-left: 1px;" height="12" width="12" /> 2<img src="bubble.png" alt="comments" style="margin-left: 2px;" height="10" width="10" /></a><a id="link11" href="/link-to-page.html">Got to page</a></td>
  <td class="row3" title="11 files">10 days</td>
  <td class="row3">104</td>
  <td class="row3">108</td>
</tr>
```

Basically I need to take those rows between `<tr>` to `</tr>` tags from source site and show them on mine.
I've tried using `preg_match_all()`, but as my regex experience is very limited I just can't do it properly.

```
preg_match_all('<tr class="hlRow"(.*?)</td></tr>/i', $turinys, $linkai, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($linkai as $linkas) {$a1 = $linkas[1]; echo "<table><tr class=\"hlRow\"".$a1."\"></td></tr></table>";}
```

Even more awesome would be to get only contents from inside of `<td>` tags and then foreach those on my page.

Comment: [use a DOM parser, fetch the tr with that class and print the outerHTML of that node. No need for regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the actual [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) question:

You need the `/s` DOTALL mode for matching across multiple lines with `(.*?)`.

And there is a space between `</td>` and `</tr>`, so it would need

```
 preg_match_all('#<tr class="hlRow"(.*?)</td>\s*</tr>#is'
```

Also notice the `#` delimiters, if you are using `/` as literal characters.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is certainly with the DOM extension rather than with regex. Parsing HTML with regex will drive you insane.

DOM code might look like this...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHtmlFile('your source url');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$rows = $xpath->query('//tr[@class="hlRow"]');

$rowNumber = 1;

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo "Row number: ", $rowNumber++, "\n";
    foreach ($row->childNodes as $td) {
        if ($td->nodeName === 'td') {
            echo $td->nodeValue, "\n";
        }
    }
    echo "End of row\n\n";
}
```